# How Can I Get This PHP Script To Successfully Insert User Input Into The MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

1) The concept is that this page requires the admin to be logged in to be able to access the add course page

(add-course.php). Any person not logged in while trying to access the page must be redirected to login.php.

But currently, it doesn't redirect non-logged in users to the login page, but instead, displays the page content.

How can I fix it?

2) The page contains a form for the site's admin to add courses to the database. But when I click on the submit

button, after filling the form, nothing is added to the database.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?

add-course.php:

```
<?php

// configuration
require("../includes/config.php");

// query users table to retrieve current admin's profile
if (array_key_exists('aid', $_GET)) {

// select a particular admin by id
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE aid=?", $_SESSION["aid"]);
$stmt->execute([$aid]); 
$admin = $stmt->fetch(); # get admin data

//if (!$admin)
if (!$_SESSION["aid"] = $admin)
{
   redirect("login.php");
   exit();
}

//Class import for image uploading
//classes is the map where the class file is stored (one above the root)
include ("../classes/upload/upload_class.php");

// if form was submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{         
    //This gets all the other information from the form
    $coursename = $_POST["c_name"];
    $course_title = $_POST["c_title"];
    $meta_keywords = $_POST["meta_keywords"];
    $meta_description = $_POST["meta_description"];
    $short_desc = $_POST["short_desc"];
    $coursedesc = $_POST["desc"];
    //$userimage = ($_FILES["userimage"]["name"]);
    $courseduration = $_POST["duration"];
    $coursecode = $_POST["code"];
    $fees = $_POST["fees"];

    // validate submission
    if (empty($_POST["c_name"]))
    {
        echo "Provide the course name.";
    }
    if (empty($_POST["duration"]))
    {
         echo "Provide the course duration.";
    }
    if (empty($_POST["code"]))
    {
         echo "Provide the course code.";
    }

    //This is the directory where images will be saved 
    $max_size = 1024*250; // the max. size for uploading

    $my_upload = new file_upload;

    $my_upload->upload_dir = "../images/courses/"; // "files" is the folder for the uploaded files (you have to create this folder)
    $my_upload->extensions = array(".png", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".jpg"); // specify the allowed extensions here
    // $my_upload->extensions = "de"; // use this to switch the messages into an other language (translate first!!!)
    $my_upload->max_length_filename = 50; // change this value to fit your field length in your database (standard 100)
    $my_upload->rename_file = true;

    $my_upload->the_temp_file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $my_upload->the_file = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $my_upload->http_error = $_FILES['image']['error'];
    $my_upload->replace = "y";
    $my_upload->do_filename_check = "n"; // use this boolean to check for a valid filename
    if ($my_upload->upload()) // new name is an additional filename information, use this to rename the uploaded file
    {
        $full_path = $my_upload->upload_dir.$my_upload->file_copy;
        $imagename = $my_upload->file_copy;
    }
    else
    {
        $imagename = "";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST["c_name"]))
    { 
        // validate coursename
        $c_name = ($_POST["c_name"]);
        //if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $coursename))
        //{
            //adminapologize("A course name can only contain letters and numbers.");
        //}
        if (strlen($c_name) < 20 || strlen($c_name) > 50)
        {
             echo "A course name must be from 20 to 50 characters.";
        }
        // validate course duration
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $courseduration))
        {
            echo "Invalid course duration.";
        }
        // validate course code
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $coursecode))
        {
            echo "A course ID can only contain letters and numbers.";
        }
        //validate course code length
        if (strlen($code) < 3 || strlen($code) > 10)
        {
             echo "A course code must be from 3 to 10 characters.";
        }
        if ($_POST["code"] === false)
        {
             echo "The course code has already been taken.";
        }
        // insert form input into database
        $result = query("INSERT INTO courses (c_name, c_title, meta_keywords, meta_description, short_desc, desc, duration, code, fees, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        $_POST["c_name"],
        $_POST["c_title"],
        $_POST["meta_keywords"],
        $_POST["meta_description"],
        $_POST["short_desc"],
        $_POST["desc"],
        $_POST["duration"],
        $_POST["code"],
        $_POST["fees"],
        $imagename);            

        // if coursename has been taken
        if ($coursename === false)
        {
             echo "An error occurred, while trying to add the course.";
        }

        // find out user's ID
        $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS user_id");
        $id = $stmt[0]["user_id"];

        // redirect to list courses
        redirect("list-courses.php");


    }
}
}

 // render the header
 include("templates/header.php");

 // render add course form
 include("templates/add-course_template.php");

// render the footer
include("templates/footer.php");
```

?>

config.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * config.php
 *
 *
 * Configures pages.
 */

// display errors, warnings, and notices
ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// requirements
require("constants.php");
require("functions.php");

// enable sessions
session_start();

// require authentication for most pages
if (!preg_match("{(admin/login|logout|register)\.php$}", $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]))
{
   if (empty($_SESSION["aid"]))
    {
       header("Location: login.php");
    }
}
elseif (!preg_match("{(?:login|logout|register)\.php$}", $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]))
{
    if (empty($_SESSION["id"]))
    {
       header("Location: login.php");
    }
}
```

?>

functions.php

```
<?php

/**
 * functions.php
 *
 * FlamyTech Computer School
 *
 * Helper functions.
 */

require_once("constants.php");

/**
 * Facilitates debugging by dumping contents of variable
 * to browser.
 */
function dump($variable)
{
    require("../templates/dump.php");
    exit;
}

/*
Check if the admin is logged in or not
*/
function adminLogin()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['aid']) || $_SESSION['aid'] == false) {
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit;
    }
}

/**
 * Logs out current user, if any.  Based on Example #1 at
 * http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php.
 */
function logout()
{
    // unset any session variables
    $_SESSION = [];

    // expire cookie
    if (!empty($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
    {
        setcookie(session_name(), "", time() - 42000);
    }

    // destroy session
    session_destroy();
}    

//Properly connect to Mysql database using PDO./*
$host = 'localhost';
$db_name   = 'comschool';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$charset";
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     $error = $e->getMessage() . ' in ' . $e->getFile() . ' on line ' . $e->getLine();
     error_log(MYSQL_DATETIME_TODAY . "|$error\r\n", 3, ERROR_LOG_PATH);
     $subject = "Database Down";
     $email_body = "The Database is down for " . APP_NAME . "\n ERROR: $error";
     send_email(ADMIN_EMAIL_TO, $subject, $email_body, ADMIN_EMAIL_FROM);
     die('<h1><span style="color:red">FATAL ERROR: No Database Connection</span></h1>');
}
```

?>

Thanks for your time and input in advance.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: Note that your `prepare` call should have *only* the query, the second argument is an array of `$driver_options` but you're passing in some session junk instead. You need to set `$aid` as that's what's used (correctly) in `execute([$aid])` but I don't see that defined anywhere. It's probably undefined and won't fetch data.

Comment: Which steps have you taken in order to debug this? Btw, that is a lot of code.

Comment: You have syntax errors, quite a few I might add. One of which is an assignment instead of a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

> But currently, it doesn't redirect non-logged in users to the login page, but instead, displays the page content.

This is caused here:

```
 if (!$_SESSION["aid"] = $admin){ 
      // if you can't set $_SESSION["aid"] to be equal to $admin then run 
      // this if loop. but this process will always be possible.
     ...
```

This will always return false (so, true) because you're **setting** the value here *not* **comparing** the value

You should be using something like:

```
 if ($_SESSION["aid"] !== $admin) { 
      // if these are not identical then execute this if statement
      ...
```

but this is comparing array's which is not a good idea, there's lots of pitfalls here; you probably want to be comparing a specific array key.

---

There is a *lot* else to look at in your code and a *lot* of less-than-ideal code here, so it will take a lot of effort to fully assess the code shown and that's frankly out of scope of this question.

One thing that does jump out is:

```
 if (array_key_exists('aid', $_GET)) {
```

Which is a verbose way of writing `if(isset($_GET['aid'])){...` but the issue is you check the `$_GET` array key exists, but then your SQL uses the `$_SESSION` data (not the $_GET data), which seems problematic; What if these values are different?

---

A quick summary of the issues I've noticed:

- Do **NOT** use MySQL Root user to connect from your PHP script. Make your own specific sub user to do this.
- Do not make functions just for the sake of it.
- **Always** follow `header` redirects with an `exit`/`die` command to cease the PHP script.
- Get into the habit from day one of [using your PHP Error Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel) rather than displaying errors to screen. One missed error output on a live website can cause a big hole in your site's safety.
- In PHP se absolute filepathing as much as possible, avoid relative (`../`) filepathing.
- `require` and `include` command lines should *not* be wrapped in brackets.
- `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` should **not** be used as it [can be compromised](http://awordpress.net/blog/dangers-in-using-php_self/) by the end user. Instead use a filepath you know can not be compromised by the user such as `$_SERVER[‘SCRIPT_NAME’]` or similar, depending on your needs.
- Be aware that your current script can be compromised by SQL injection attacks.

---

## Final thoughts:

Follow the comments under your question. Read the links they point to.

Read about [How to learn PHP correctly](https://phptherightway.com/) and [how to avoid PHP delusions](https://phpdelusions.net/) as well as [**How to secure your database against SQL Injection attacks**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: How can this script be compromised by SQL injection attacks?

Comment: Can you quote, because I still can't see it

Comment: `$result = query("INSERT INTO courses` query seems to be a custom function that is not shown in the code but accepts `$_POST` values and from viewing all the rest of the code from the OP, it simply wont be a prepared statement. 99.9% sure `:-p`

Comment: I don't know why you think that since they used prepared statements in the same piece of code few lines above: `"SELECT * FROM admin WHERE aid=?"` Besides if they are using placeholders you can assume that this is because of parameterization. Whether via prepared statements or escaping it should still prevent SQL injection as long as you parameterize.